# How to send custom objects in WCF Message

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server, message

I wanted to send one custom object in `system.servicemodel.Channels.Message`. Like

```
public class person
{
    string Id;
    string Name;
}

MessageVersion mv = MessageVersion.Create(Soap12);
String action = "Msg";

Message msg = Message.Create(mv, action, new person());

serviceref.ProcessMsg(msg) // this is my service reference in client

//when i tried to access this in Service like 
person p = msg.GetBody<person>()
//I am getting an serialization exception
//I have the Person class on both client and service side
```

Can some one please help me in figure out my error?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're looking for a [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx):

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class person
{
    [DataMember]
    string Id;

    [DataMember]
    string Name; 
}
```

Check out [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) for more information on DataContracts and WCF.

**EDIT**

Not sure if this will do the trick or not, but as I noted in my response to your comment, there's an overload of the CreateMessage method that takes an XmlObjectSerializer.  MSDN docs on it are rather thin, but I *think* something like this might do it:

```
Message msg = Message.Create(mv, action, new person(), new DataContractSerializer(typeof(person)));
```

I haven't tested this, but at the least it may get you pointed in the right direction.

The `DataContractSerializer` will need to be supplied a DataContract (`person` in the first part of my answer).

Comment: Hey, I tried this one but the input and output for my Service contract is only System.ServiceModel.Channel.Message. Since the person is not  the direct input it wont help me i think.

Comment: @realn - What if you used on of the alternate CreateMessage methods - there's one that takes a fourth parameter for an XmlObjectSerializer:  [Message.CreateMessage Method (MessageVersion, String, Object, XmlObjectSerializer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195454.aspx)

Comment: Error in line 1 position 695. Expecting element 'Person' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DCS'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'string', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.

Comment: That's the Message i got SerializationException Caught.

Comment: @realn - did you decorate the Person class with the `[DataContract]` attribute and the fields with `[DataMember]`?  Based on the namespaces in the error it looks like you might not have.